# getting blank in Firestore recycler view in Fragment fetching a field and filtering data in recycler view based on that field

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, fragment

Fetching required field from Firestore:

```
public class OrderFragment extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    View v;
    String userID, userEmail;
    FirebaseFirestore fStore;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    ProgressDialog progress;
    NoteAdapter adapter;
    TextView user_Email;
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_order, container, false);
            fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Section");
            //userref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
             fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
```

When I do not pass any criteria in query it works fine i.e. it shows all documents, when I put a hardcoded value as filter criteria it works fine - but a variable does not return anything - there is no error.

I've highlighted the criteria in bold below - fetching the string and passing the same string as criteria:

```
userID = Objects.requireNonNull(fAuth.getCurrentUser()).getUid();
user_Email=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.user_Email);
DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("Users").document(userID);
documentReference.addSnapshotListener((Activity) getContext(), new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    **@Override
    public void onEvent(@javax.annotation.Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @javax.annotation.Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
        userEmail = documentSnapshot.getString("Email").trim();
    }
});
user_Email.setText(userEmail);**

FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Note> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Note>()
        
**.setQuery(FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Section").whereEqualTo("ALoggedInUser",userEmail), Note.class)
                        .build();**
```

Adapter Listening:

```
recyclerView=(RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_View);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    adapter = new NoteAdapter(options);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.startListening();
    return v;
}
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view,@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onViewCreated(view,savedInstanceState);
        this.v=view;
        progress=new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progress.setTitle("Loading");
        progress.setMessage("Syncing");
        progress.setCancelable(true);
        progress.show();
    }
}
```

Dependencies:

```
package com.example.aba;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
    import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
    import com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener;
    import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
    import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException;
    import java.util.Objects;
```

Comment: You're supposed to use triple backquotes to format code, not triple apostrophes.

Comment: thanks Doug, have edited the post to correct the format

Comment: And what is your question now?

Comment: When I do not pass any criteria in query it works fine i.e. it shows all documents, when I put a hardcoded value as filter criteria it works fine - but a variable does not return anything - there is no error.